# Do I need to close the file when using YAML::load?

Tags: ruby

like the following line of code

```
sites = YAML::load(File.open(SITESPATH))
```

is it necessary to change to

```
File.open(SITESPATH) do |file|
  sites = YAML::load(file)
end
```

just in order to make it sure that file got closed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should close the file, so your **second example** is the correct one.

Just as a side-note, remember that the `sites` variable will not be visible outside the block, unless you already created it before the block.

Because `IO.open`, when called with block, returns the value of the block, you may use:

```
sites = File.open(SITESPATH) {|file| YAML::load(file) }
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `YAML.load_file(filename)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really about YAML::load so much as it is about File/IO streams generally.

Called without a block, File.open is exactly the same as File.new. This doesn't close a file on its own, so you would need to close it yourself.

From the **[documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html#M000069)**:

> With no associated block, [File.]open is a synonym for IO.new. If the
>   optional code block is   given, it will be passed io as an argument,
>   and the IO object will automatically be closed when the block
>   terminates. In this instance, IO.open returns the value of the block.